# Importing c# DLL that invokes WCF functionality to PowerShell

Tags: c#, wcf, powershell, svcutil.exe, powershell-module

I have a WCF service for which I generated an interface using the following command:

```
svcutil.exe net.pipe://localhost/myService/MEX
```

I created a new binding as follows:

```
var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 104857600;
binding.MaxBufferSize = 104857600;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 104857600;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 104857600;
binding.Security.Mode = NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None;
binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None;
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/myService/MEX");
IMyService service = ChannelFactory<IMyService>.CreateChannel(binding, endpoint);
```

When I tried using the module in PowerShell I got the following error:

> Write-File : The message with Action 'http://tempuri.org/IMyService/StartDisk' cannot be processed at the receiver,
>   due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch
>   (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.
>   Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g.
>   Message, Transport, None).
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> Write-File bla -verbose
>
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-File], ActionNotSupportedException
>
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ServiceModel.ActionNotSupportedException,DLM.Module.WriteFile

I'm using `[ProtoContract]` as the serialization protocol. I had to manually add it to the IMyService interface that was generated by the SvcUtil.exe command.

```
selfHost = new ServiceHost(reqsApi, pipeBaseAddress);
       var pipeBinding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
       pipeBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 104857600;
       pipeBinding.MaxBufferSize = 104857600;
       pipeBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 104857600;
       pipeBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 104857600;
       pipeBinding.Security.Mode = NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None;
       pipeBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None;
       selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
            typeof(T),
            pipeBinding,
            new StringBuilder().Append(serviceName).ToString());
       ServiceMetadataBehavior SMB = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
       selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(SMB);
       var behaviour = selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute();
       behaviour.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;
       var debug = selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior();
       debug.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
       var serviceEndpoint = selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange),
                                                         MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexNamedPipeBinding(),
                                                         new StringBuilder().Append(serviceName).Append("/mex").ToString());
       var behaviorExtension = new ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoBehaviorExtension();
```

Any thoughts on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks a little bit strange that your service URL ends with /MEX suffix. Typically you would just use `net.pipe://localhost/myService` URL.

Comment: I'm using named pipes and I don't want to use http to get the metadata hence using mex. You can read about the difference [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2011/08/10/wsdl-vs-mex-knockout-or-tie/)

Comment: Yes, I see. But that's what you use for svcutil.exe to create an `IService` interface for you. But when you create a channel you don't need "MEX" suffix. Try to change `EndpointAddress` constructor to this: `new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/myService")`, because I believe you main service (with actions like `StartDisk` is listening on `net.pipe://localhost/myService` endpoint).

Comment: Even though you didn't specify what value `serviceName` has, I still think that you have to fix your client code to remove `/MEX/` suffix from the endpoint address. Because at the server side you have `selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
            typeof(T),
            pipeBinding,
            new StringBuilder().Append(serviceName).ToString());` and it means that the service is listening on the address without `/MEX` (because you add it when adding second endpoint few lines below). So, try to remove `/MEX` from client code and see what happens.